# bash substring args using sed; nested quotes issue?

Tags: bash, sed, nested

I have a command, gennlm.sh, that expects two arguments -- input file and output folder. I want to get every file in a directory, use these for input, and then transform each input filename to provide an output folder, and set this all up as a cronjob. this is what I have so far:

```
10 */6 * * * for file in /var/www/parsingdev/corpus/*; do bash /var/www/parsingdev/meTypeset/tools/gennlm.sh $file '$file | sed -e "s/.*\//\/var\/www\/parsingdev\/output\//g" -e "s/\.docx//g"'; done
```

However, there seems to be something wrong with how I'm trying to make the the second argument work, with all of the substring functions nested in ' ', as the intended string argument isn't being passed as expected to the gennlm.sh script. Mind clarifying what I need to do to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: you are better off writing a wrapper script instead of for loop in crontab , i have never seen anyone doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables in single quotes.

Instead, do

```
10 */6 * * * for file in /var/www/parsingdev/corpus/*; do fileX=${file%.docx}; bash /var/www/parsingdev/meTypeset/tools/gennlm.sh ${fileX##*/}; done
```

I hope I understand what's a non-sense in your original command :

```
'$file | sed -e "s/.*\//\/var\/www\/parsingdev\/output\//g" -e "s/\.docx//g"
```

### NOTE

"Double quote" *every* expansion, and anything that could contain a special character, eg. "$var", "$@", "${array[@]}", "$(command)". Use 'single quotes' to make something literal, eg. 'Costs $5 USD'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words.

Comment: ah, of course, thanks! I knew I could wrap it all in a $() but I forgot I had to use echo in there to actually execute something sensibly.

Comment: Post edited with a working code to keep only the filename without extension and path like you seems to try

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your sed is supposed to take the basename of the file and remove its `.docx` extension (if any), and prepend a path to it. Then, since you're already launching a bash, why not do everything in bash?

```
for file in /var/www/parsingdev/corpus/*; do bash -c 'out=${1##*/}; /var/www/parsingdev/meTypeset/tools/gennlm.sh "$1" "/var/www/parsingdev/output/${out%.docx}"' _ "$file"; done
```

or really everything in bash:

```
bash -c 'for file in /var/www/parsingdev/corpus/*; do out=${file##*/}; /var/www/parsingdev/meTypeset/tools/gennlm.sh "$file" "/var/www/parsingdev/output/${out%.docx}"; done'
```